# Управление мышкой

Tags: three.js

Есть сцена, игровое поле `Plane` и объект `Box`.

Как можно с помощью мыши передвигать этот объект (т.е. нажимаешь где-нибудь на поле мышкой - и объект туда передвигается)? И как сделать так, чтобы камера передвигалась за объектом?

Я даже не знаю, как попробовать. Я никак не пробовал. Есть вариант, в инете накопал какой-то eventscontrols, думаю через него попробовать, но инфы по нём никакой не нашёл, придётся методом тыка с изучением кода, может, чё и получится.

Comment: А что у вас получилось, как вы пробовали?

Comment: в том то и суть, я даже не знаю, как попробовать. Я никак не пробовал. Есть вариант, в инете накопал какой-то eventscontrols, думаю через него попробовать, но инфы по нём никакой не нашёл, придётся методом тыка с изучением кода, может, чё и получится

Comment: через Raycast нужно "бросить" луч, который на Plane и определит точку
И позицию камеры изменить по такому же принципу, только прибавлением разницы позиций Бокса до и после

Comment: Спс! Уловил суть. Щас попробуем. А теперь у меня ещё один вопрос созрел. А систему столкновений(collision) тоже через это же raycast делается. да??

Comment: @HashNoobs ну вроде да:

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

из http://hashcode.ru/questions/400295/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0-three-js?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=400447#400447